# How to prove that $\sum_{d|n}d^{-\varepsilon}\leq C(\varepsilon)n^{\varepsilon}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I wanna prove that for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there is a constant $C(\varepsilon)$ such that  $$\sum_{d|n}d^{-\varepsilon}\leq C(\varepsilon)n^{\varepsilon}$$ 
but I do not know where I have to start. Some hints please.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is true even for $\epsilon=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for every $\epsilon>0$ holds $$\frac{1}{d^{\epsilon}}\leq1.$$

Comment: Thanks ! Since $\frac{1}{d^{\varepsilon}}\leq 1$ then  $\sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d^{\varepsilon}}\leq \sigma_0(n)$ and I know that $\sigma_0(n)\ll_{\varepsilon} n^{\varepsilon}$  for any $\varepsilon>0.$ So we have $\sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d^{\varepsilon}}\ll_{\varepsilon}n^{\varepsilon}.$ Right ?

Comment: @Med Yes, it's right ;)